# Count down with setInterval has time difference

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let count = 60;

function timeLeft(){
    count = count - 1;
    if(count == 0){
        count = 60;
    }
}

setInterval(() => timeLeft(), 1000)
setInterval(() => machoAirline.changePrice(), 60000);
setInterval(() => yenoTech.changePrice(), 60000);
```

This code is the countdown for showing how much time is left until stocks' prices change. But after some minutes, there is a gap between counter and prices update.

console:

```
price updated!
counter: 42
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What is `machoAirline` and `yenoTech`?

Comment: What is the result you expect

Comment: The problem is that you're misuing `setInterval()` and expecting it to keep accurate time and it is not designed to do that.  `setInterval()` intervals are approximate only.   Look at the wall time when the interval is called if you want to know the real time elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout and intervals may take [longer to fire](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) when you want due to:

- inactive of tabs
- throttling of tracking scripts
- Late timeouts because browser busy with other tasks.

If you need correct order of `machoAirline` and `yenoTech` execution you can combine them in one setInterval:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  machoAirline.changePrice();
  yenoTech.changePrice();
}, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` does not keep accurate time, as described in other answers. This means that calculating elapsed time by counting the invocations of `setInterval` will result in inaccurate timings when compared to wall-time (or indeed, other intervals that you have set).

[`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) is the most accurate measure of time available in the browser.

If timing is critical, then consider polling `performance.now()` in the body of a `setInterval` callback that runs at a short interval...

Something like:

```js
const now = performance.now();
const finishTime = now + 3000; // 3s time

const handle = setInterval(() => {
  if (performance.now() >= finishTime) {
    console.log("some action");
    clearInterval(handle); // kill the timer
  }
}, 100); // poll every 100ms (ish)
```